# discord.py change bot status every 60 sec

Tags: bots, discord.py, status

I'm trying to make a code that change the status on the bot every 60 second but I can't get it to work. I searched around how to make it but it seems like no one have tried to do this. Or at least I couldn't find anything like that.

I tried this code but it didn't work, the bot never changes to the second status =/

```
# Bot joins server/auto msg
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    log_channel = bot.get_channel(log_id)
    join_embed = discord.Embed(title='Rosy is back online', color=0xd3d3d3)
    join_embed.set_author(name='')
    await log_channel.send(embed=join_embed)
    while True:
        await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name='?help if you are wondering anything'))  # First status
        time.sleep(60)  # Wait 60 seconds
        await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name='TEST!'))  # Show second status then repeat
```

I also want the second status to show total members in the discord server...

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT:**

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=10.0)
async def my_background_task():
    """Will loop every 60 seconds and change the bots presence"""
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name='?help if you are wondering anything'))
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name='TEST!'))


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    # Waiting until the bot is ready
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    # Starting the loop
    my_background_task.start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution and it works perfect, it randomly changes the status.

## Custom bot status

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=40)  # How often the bot should change status, mine is set on every 40 seconds
async def changepresence():
    global x

    game = iter(
        [
            "Status 1",
            "Status 2",
            "Status 3",
            "Status 4",
            "Status 5?",
            "Status 6",
        ]
    )  # Every line above ^^ is one new status the bot can have
    for x in range(random.randint(1, 6)):  # Here you write the total of different status you have for the bot, I have 6 and that's why I have number 6 there. This makes it a 16.666% chance to change status every 40 second
        x = next(game)
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name=x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tasks.loop` for that, here's how:

```py
from discord.ext import tasks

@tasks.loop(seconds=60.0)
async def my_background_task():
    """Will loop every 60 seconds and change the bots presence"""
    await bot.change_presence(...)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    # Waiting until the bot is ready
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    # Starting the loop
    my_background_task.start()
```

[docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=tasks#discord.ext.tasks.Loop)

EDIT:

Answering your comment:

```py
total_members = []

for guild in bot.guilds:
    total_members.expand(guild.members)

# Number of total members the bot is `serving` in all guilds, without duplicates
total_members_count = len(set(total_members))
```

EDIT2:

```py
await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name=f'Member count: {total_member_count}'))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really understand. Where do I put the second status? Under the first one? I am sorry for asking, I'm a beginner to discord.py =/

Comment: what do you mean by `under the first one`?

Comment: Look at "EDIT" on my text above, is it supposed to be like that?

Comment: if you want some sort of delay between changing the presences add `await asyncio.sleep(seconds)`

Comment: It doesn't work, I got this error 
```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Command.__call__' was never awaited
  @bot.event
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Comment: Nvm it works @ŁukaszKwieciński, but one last thing, how do I make the status to tell the amount of members the server have?

Comment: Sorry again, I know to to make the member count but what I don't understand is how I put it in the status. 
I saved the member count as ``member_count`` and when I try to put it in the status it doesn't work, this is what I did.
``await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name=member_count, ' Members!'))``

Comment: That's basic python, but whatever, check the second edit

Comment: It kinda works =/
It works but shows wrong amount of members, in the server it's 2 members (me and the bot) but it shows 0 instead of 2

Comment: do you have `intents.members` enabled?

Comment: No don't think so? I also have 2 other problems, after 1 minute of the bot being online it just goes offline then the console is being spammed by ``socket.send() raised exception.``

Comment: I just saw that I have ``intents.members`` is true/enabled

Answer (score 0):

@tasks.loop(seconds=40)  # How often the bot should change status, mine is set on every 40 seconds
async def changepresence():
global x

```
game = iter(
    [
        "Status 1",
        "Status 2",
        "Status 3",
        "Status 4",
        "Status 5?",
        "Status 6",
    ]
)  # Every line above ^^ is one new status the bot can have
for x in range(random.randint(1, 6)):  # Here you write the total of different status you have for the bot, I have 6 and that's why I have number 6 there. This makes it a 16.666% chance to change status every 40 second
    x = next(game)
await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name=x))
```